# PDO - Mostrando informações do banco

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo, aplicação-web

Ao tentar conectar ao Banco de Dados sem conexão a internet o programa me mostra essa mensagem de erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Network is unreachable in /Library/WebServer/Documents/solucoes/includes/conexao.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/solucoes/includes/conexao.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=teste_sis', 'user123', 'senha123', Array) #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/solucoes/includes/logar.php(7): con() #2 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/solucoes/includes/conexao.php on line 6
```

Essa mesma mensagem me mostra tanto o Host do banco quanto usuário e senha, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de ocultar essa informações ou se existe algum erro no meu código de conexão com o banco.

Código da conexão PDO:

```php
function con (){
    $user = "user123";
    $senha = "senha123";
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=186.111.111.111;dbname=teste_sis", $user, $senha,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));    
    return $pdo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atente-se ao "*Uncaught PDOException*". Basta capturar a exceção lançada nesse caso e tratar da forma que desejar.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Em manutenção!');
}
```

Pode ler mais sobre na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php).